# loop through a directory and check if it exist in another directory

Tags: linux, bash, loops, if-statement, redhat

I have a folder with 20000 files in directory  A and another folder
with 15000 file in another directory B i can loop through a directory
using:

```
DIR='/home/oracle/test/forms1/'

for FILE in "$DIR"*.mp
do
   filedate=$( ls -l --time-style=+"date %d-%m-%Y_%H-%M" *.fmx |awk  '{print $8 $7}')
    echo "file New Name $FILE$filedate "
#    echo "file New Name $FILE is copied "
done
```

I need to loop through all the files in directory A and check if they
exist in directory B

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
testdir='/home/oracle/ideatest/test/'
livedir='/home/oracle/ideatest/live/'

for FILET in "$testdir" #
do
    testfile=$(ls $FILET)
    echo $testfile

    for FILEL in "$livedir"
    do
        livefile=$(ls $FILEL)

        if [ "$testfile" = "$livefile" ]
        then
            echo "$testfile"
            echo "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
        else
            echo "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"
        fi
    done
done
```

> i'am trying to fix the result of years of bad version control we have
>   that very oly script that send a form to live enviorment but every
>   time it's compiled and sent the live version is named like
>   (testform.fmx)  but in test dir there is like 10 files named like
>   (testform.fmx01-12-2018)
>   (testform.fmx12-12-2017)(testform.fmx04-05-2016) as a reuslt we lost
>   track of the last source sent to live enviroment that's why i created
>   this

```
filedate=$( ls -l --time-style=+"date %d-%m-%Y_%H-%M" *.fmx |awk 
'{print $8 $7}')
```

> ```
> echo "file New Name $FILE$filedate "
> ```

to match the format and loop through each dir and using ls i can find the last version by matching the size and the year and month

Comment: For every file in testdir, you only need to check if a file with the same name exists in livedir. You don't need to iterate over all the files in livedir to do that. If you strip the path from FILET and replace it with the path of livedir, you only need to check if `ls "${livedir}/${BASEFILET}"` returns true.
Alternatively, you could do a sorted ls in both directories and feed the output of both to `diff`.

Comment: I don't get it. Maybe you want to get the newest file in the `testdir`  that does not exists in the `livedir`? Do you want to do it recursively? Does directories matter?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the `testdir=...` code, including two critical ones.

Comment: Using `ls` to make lists of files doesn't work in general.  See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: The critical problems are essentially the same: `for var in "..."` loops just once, and is equivalent to `var="..."`.

Comment: the case that we don't have version control all i have is a directory full of .fmx and another with the sources .fmb the fmb got a time stamp but the .fmx doesn't that's the reason for the loop to attach a time stamp then i will try to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basicly use `diff` command to compare the files and directories. `diff folderA folderB`
I think you do not really need to use a loop for that..

If really you want to use a loop around, you may want to compare the files as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR1="/home/A"
DIR2="/home/B"
CmpCmn=/usr/bin/cmp
DiffCmn=/usr/bin/diff

for file1 in $DIR1/*; do #Get the files under DIR1 one by one
        filex=$(basename $file1) #Get only the name ofthe ile
        echo "searching for $filex"
         $DiffCmn $filex $DIR2  #Check whether the file is under DIR2 or not
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
                echo " No file with $filex name under $DIR2 folder"
        else
                echo " $filex exists under $DIR2" 
                $CmpCmn  $file1 $DIR2/$filex  #Compare if the files are exactly same
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                then
                         echo " $filex is not same"
                 else
                         echo " $filex is the same"
                 fi
fi
        done
```

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several issues with this code.

Comment: @pjh the code is draft, not really completed and just to give an idea.. on the otherhand, i will use Shellcheck for the upcoming answers so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This code is based on the code in the question:

```
testdir='/home/oracle/ideatest/test/'
livedir='/home/oracle/ideatest/live/'

shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # Globs match files whose names start with '.'

for testpath in "$testdir"*
do
    [[ -f $testpath ]] || continue  # Skip non-files

    testfile=${testpath##*/}        # Get file (base) name
    printf '%s\n' "$testfile"
    livepath=${livedir}${testfile}  # Make path to (possible) file in livedir

    if [[ -f $livepath ]]
    then
        printf '%s\n' "$testfile"
        echo "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    else
        echo "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @MohamedHussain, thanks for the feedback but please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find files that are [comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm)on in both A and B directories.

```
comm -12 \
    <(cd A && find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | sort) \
    <(cd B && find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | sort)
```

Live version available at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/QDHBsz).

1. How it works? find's list the files in both A and B directories and `comm` displays only files/lines common in both inputs. `comm` needs input to be sorted, that's why `| sort`
2. Don't parse `ls` output. `ls` is for nice, formatted output. Use `find .` and parse it's output.

Comment: it won't work for i need to do i have added the rest of the case above